# php delete a line from log file that matches with some string value

Tags: php

I am new to php. I am trying to delete a line from log file that matches with some string value.

Below is the code able to display the matched line from log file, but I wanna delete that line  and append with rest of lines of log file.

**Below is my code:**

```
<?php
$searchthis = "mystring";
$matches = array();

$handle = @fopen("myfile.log", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($handle);

        if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

//show results:
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**EDIT:**
**Lines in log file:**

```
john abraham hml3
john abraham hml1
```

$search_string = 'hml3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function

```
function search_and_delete($_file,$search_string){
        $file = file($_file);
        foreach ($file as $line_index => $line) {
            if(strpos($line, $search_string) !== false){
                unset($file[$line_index]);
                break;
            }
        }       
        file_put_contents($_file, implode("",$file));
}
```

Sample usage

```
search_and_delete("/var/a.txt","removing_line_conteins");
```

Comment: hey, its deleting every line from log file. I mean as soon as I refersh the page, its deleting each line from log file everytime, not looking to the specific string perfectly

Comment: its remove only the first line which is containts the $search_string. What is wrong ?

Comment: yes, it deletes that line. But if you refresh the page, other top line getting deleted. Refresh again, another top gets deleted even if there is no match with the string.

Comment: what $search_string variable has ?.

Comment: I just updated log lines in my post. could you please check below 'Edit' in above post.

Comment: So, its remove 'john abraham hml3'. And delete after refresh 'john abraham hml1' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80574/discussion-between-dalim-cepic-and-john).

Comment: Yes it removes hml3 line as soon as I run your script. if i run your script again, it deletes another line too even if the string doesn't match with the line.

Comment: Buddy, your code works perfectly.. I didnt seen this line: $search_string = "c";  so not worked for me before... Sorry I overlooked,.

Answer (score 1):

Make array of file lines and select what you need

```
$searchthis = "mystring";
$matches = array();

$handle = file("myfile.log");
foreach ($handle as $buffer)
        if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) === FALSE)
            $matches[] = $buffer;

//show results:
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: hey, how can I delete that line and append with remaining lines.?

Comment: `$matches` contains only selected lines.

Comment: Yes, I got to understand your code, but I wanna know how can I delete that line from my log file and remaining lines should append automatically? So, how can I achieve this?

Comment: IE, you want modify log file don't stop appending it? I am not ready to answer right now. May be, you make another question to use common mind? :)